# Task lifestate when reaching the home screen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, homescreen

Android documentation on [Task & Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) clearly states that when the activities comprising a given task are destroyed due the the user repeatedly pressing the back button the *"task no longer exists"*.

Here's the snippet from the documentation:

> If the user continues to press Back, then each activity in the stack is popped off to reveal the previous one, until the user returns to the Home screen (or to whichever activity was running when the task began). When all activities are removed from the stack, the task no longer exists.

However, I'm wondering what is the precise meaning of the statement  "the task no longer exists".

Since every time an activity is popped off the stack it gets destroyed, by the time we reach the home screen all activities will be gone and the task will be empty. I would assume this to cause the destruction of the task itself (as per the documentation, "the task will cease to exist"). However, when pressing the overview button, the root activity of the allegedly-destroyed task is still visible. If selected, the root activity is re-created (i.e., the `onCreate()` callback is invoked).

Since the concept of *task* as defined in the official documentation is not so much discussed in third-party tutorials, I cannot find a authoritative explanation of this behavior. Can somebody enlighten me?

Thanks!